# Can we connect to multiple clients/connections for same room that is emitted using flask socketio?

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio

```
emit('send_to_user',data,room=user_id)
```

How do we send the same emit to multiple clients/connections on client side?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all the clients in a room, and then address the message to that room.

Documentation for rooms is [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#rooms).

Example of adding and removing a client from a room:

```py
from flask_socketio import join_room, leave_room

@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    join_room(room)
    send(username + ' has entered the room.', room=room)

@socketio.on('leave')
def on_leave(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    leave_room(room)
    send(username + ' has left the room.', room=room)
```

Once your clients are in the room, you can emit to all the people in the room just by setting the `room` argument to the room name.

Comment: How does the client receive this? Like if the client is active in multiple connections.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The client receives an event, in the same way it receives any other events.

Comment: The issue is on web browser, if I'm logged in with one user and he's opened more than one tab and he's active on an another system, the user receives socket response only on one tab and not on other.